# Unable to call a built in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to call a built in procedure in oracle with this command:

```
CALL ttOptEstimateStats( 'orders_100_opt', 1, '10 PERCENT' );
```

I get this error:

```
CALL ttOptEstimateStats( 'orders_100_opt', 1, '10 PERCENT' )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
06576. 00000 -  "not a valid function or procedure name"
*Cause:    Could not find a function (if an INTO clause was present) or
           a procedure (if the statement did not have an INTO clause) to
           call.
*Action:   Change the statement to invoke a function or procedure
```

What should be changed in my code? how can I solve this?

Comment: show your procedure please

Comment: I have no procedure. I found it from [hier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21643/proced.htm#TTREF264)

Comment: Is it Times Ten In-memory DB?

Comment: I am using it for another DB

Comment: @Kaja In order to execute a procedure, you have to use `exec <procedurename>`